# How can i make a button actvate my searchSpell function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

i am finishing my first react project. But I cant make this button work. I keep giving me the same error below

error console message: Uncaught TypeError_axios_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.request is not a function

code:
function Header(){

```
const { searchSpell } = Hooker();
const [whatSpell, setWhatSpell] = useState()

function pesquisar () {
    if(!whatSpell){
        alert("escreva alguma coisa antes de pesquisar")
        return
    } else{
        return searchSpell(whatSpell)
    }
}
```

another code:

```
import { SpellContext } from "../provider.js"
function Hooker (){
    const { spellState, searchSpell } = useContext(SpellContext)
    return { spellState, searchSpell }
}
export default Hooker
```

and the function one:

```
function BaseInfo({ children }){

    const [spellState, setSpellState] = useState({
        name: undefined,
        desc: undefined,
        higher_level: undefined,
        range: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        material: undefined,
        ritual: false,
        duration: undefined,
        concentration: false,
        casting_time: undefined,
        level: 0,
    });

    const searchSpell = (spellName) => {
        api.request(spellName).then(function(response) {
            setSpellState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                name: response.data.name,
                desc: response.data.desc,
                higher_level: response.data.higher_level,
                range: response.data.range,
                components: response.data.components,
                material: response.data.material,
                ritual: response.data.ritual,
                duration: response.data.duration,
                concentration: response.data.concentration,
                casting_time: response.data.duration,
                level: response.data.duration,
            })
            )
        })

        console.log(spellState.duration)
    }

    const contextValue = {
        spellState,
        searchSpell: useCallback((spellName) => searchSpell(spellName), []),
    }

    return(
        <SpellContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </SpellContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default BaseInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the button's fault.  The error message indicates you're calling `searchSpell`, but there is something wrong with the way you're writing the API request.

If you're using `axios` as the error suggests. Check the [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro) for proper installation, importing and usage.

Example usage for your use case:

```
import axios from "axios"

// ... ...

axios.request(spellName).then(function() {
  // ... ...
```